# Losing java main args when using getopts in launch script

Tags: java, bash, getopts

I have a script with 5 mandatory parameters (5 paths) and 3 options (-d for debug, -l  for log4j override, -s  for another override).

I'm managing it with getopts. The following script is simplified :

```
LOG4J_FILE=$DEFAULT_LOG4J_FILE
S_FILE=$DEFAULT_S_FILE
ECLIPSE_PROPS=

while getopts "l:s:d" flag; do
case "$flag" in
   l) LOG4J_FILE="$OPTARG";;
   s) S_FILE="$OPTARG";;
   d) ECLIPSE_PROPS="-Xdebug ...";;
   :) usage;;
   ?) usage;;
esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
OPTIND=1

...

echo_and_eval $JAVA $ECLIPSE_PROPS -Dlog4.configuration=$LOG4J_FILE -Ds.file=$S_FILE -cp $CLASSPATH $MAIN_CLASS $ARGS
```

If I just put the 5 parameters, it works.
If I add one or two optional with parameters (l or s), it works.
If I add the -d option, **I have no args in the Java main method**.

Any clue ? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Run your script with `bash -ex ./script.sh` to get debug info.

Comment: I've done it but anyway, the final java command line seems totally ok to me. I "sysout" the args parameter in the java main method. It is empty.

Comment: Can you show relevant Java code for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's **OPTARG** not OPTARGS -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-getopts

```
l) LOG4J_FILE="$OPTARG";;
```

I would encourage you to get into the habit of quoting ALL your variables, that will protect any that contain whitespace or globbing chars:

```
java "$ECLIPSE_PROPS" -Dlog4.configuration="$LOG4J_FILE" -Ds.file="$S_FILE" -cp "$CLASSPATH" Main "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"
```

Comment: Could have been that but this is just a mistype in my question. I'll fix it. This is OPTARG in my code. And the final script line is something like echo_and_eval "$JAVA $JVM_OPTIONS -cp $CLASSPATH $MAIN_CLASS $ARGS"

Comment: Read this: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: +1 on quoting parameter expansions, but note that it's not necessary on assignments (e.g. `LOG4j_FILE=$OPTARG;;` )

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `echo` to output the command line isn't going to show you how it gets parsed into individual arguments.  `foo 'bar baz'` and `foo bar baz` are two very different commands, but they look the same when `echo`ed.

Clearly, something in the actual value of the `ECLIPSE_PROPS` variable (that is, the argument to `-d`) is preventing the later arguments from being passed to the Java main method.  If you supplied the actual code and actual values, we might be able to help you determine what that is.